# Notifications using noticed gem Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

I'm writing the documentation about my Rails' project and I have a question.
I developed the notification's mechanism with the GoRails tutorial and the code is something like this, Me question is this is a controller or a model logic? I think controller logic but I am not sure

```
class EventNotification < Noticed::Base
    deliver_by :database
 
    def message
      @group=Group.find(params[:group][:id])
      @user=User.find(params[:user][:id])
      @event=Event.find(params[:event][:id])
      "#{@event.user.username} invite you in #{@event.title} into #{@group.name} click here to visit"
    end
  
    #
    def url
     group_event_path(Group.find(params[:group][:id]), Event.find(params[:event][:id]) )
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with UML?

Comment: I need to build the diagram class of my Rails' project

Comment: So I don't know how to represent this

Comment: In that case you should ask it accordingly. Please edit your question. Anyhow, from a UML perspective the main question would be irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, and if you ask two questions in one it's likely to be closed as unfocused. So leave this without the UML part and ask that ask a different one once you clarified whether it's a controller or not . (Does not look like Model since that's about data persistence.)

Comment: The principal question is if this class here is a controller or a model so I can represent it into my diagram class in the best way possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248267/discussion-between-alessia-volpi-and-qwerty-so).

Comment: The chat is a dead horse. This way it's fine. Come back with the UML-part as a new question once you clarified the above.

Comment: I think this is controller logic, because it's a class that inherits from Noticed::Base and is used to send notifications. It's not a model because it's not a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and it's not a class used to interact with the database.